# What are the common forms of these sentences?

Tags: wordplay, rebus

What are the common forms of these sentences?

1. Those with greater vertical displacement, achieve more damaging impact upon losing all of their gravitational potential energy.
2. [image: YOU'RE IN MY SOURCE CODE!]
3. Question|noitseuQ
4. 

````
                     .--._..--.
              ___   ( _'-_  -_.'
          _.-'   `-._|  - :- |
      _.-'           `--...__|
   .-'                       '--..___
  / `._      C♂R                     \
   `. `._                       6 mi  |
     `. `._                           /
       '. `._    :__________....-----'
         `..`---'    |-_  _- |___...----..._
                     |_....--'             `.`.
               _...--'                       `.`.
          _..-'                      6km   _.'.'
       .-'                               _.'.'
       |      Rouge                     _.'.'
       |                   __....------'-'
       |     __...------''' _|
       '--'''        |-  - _ |
               _.-''''''''''''''''''-._
            _.'                        |\
          .'    2mi                  _.' |
          `._            Ventriculus  |:.'
            `._            Gaster   _.' |
               `..__                 |  |
                    `---.._.--.    _|  |
                     | _   - | `-.._|_.'
          .--...__   |   -  _|
         .'_      `--.....__ |
        .'_                 `--..__
       .'_     Clupea               `.
      .'_          Harengus           `-.
      `--..____                   2km  _`.
               ```--...____          _..--'
                     | - _ ```---.._.'
                     |   - _ |
                     |_ -  - |:
````

[[Source]](http://ascii.co.uk/art/signpost)

5.

> MAD!

Hint for #2

> Quark was close because of *what he did*, not *what he wrote*

Hint 2 for #2

> Action1: **HELLO THERE!**
>  Word1: *hello*
>  Action2: **I'M HERE TOO**
>  Word2: *We know*

Hint for #5

> Just forget about it. Otherwise you'll be driven insane.

Hint 2 for #5

> Invisible, insane

Comment: I'll bet number 2 is "Hello there!" ;-)

Comment: I bet it's not ;)

Comment: I don't think 2 works quite as well as the others. But I wasn't gonna not put it in after the effort of making the video

Comment: Any chance we can get a hint or nudge in the right direction on 2 and 5?

Comment: They're both proverbs. Quite common ones

Comment: Just so nobody wastes time on it, there is nothing hidden in #2's source code ;) (I checked individual frames, the container, bit encryption, the works which in hindsight was pretty dumb).

Comment: @Quark little do you know it, but what you've *done* is actually a bit of a clue

Comment: @AggieKidd Should I just give the final answer since I don't think it was the best constructed clue anyway?

Comment: @JamesWebster I'm afraid I'm at a loss, and I'd love to know. I'd be ok with you editing my answer to insert it, just make some note that you added that part.

Comment: @JamesWebster I like it. I never would have gotten number 2, but I really like the puzzle!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Partial Answer

1.Those with greater vertical displacement, achieve more damaging impact upon losing all of their gravitational potential energy.

> The bigger they are, the harder they fall.

2. Image (From OP)

> Actions speak louder than words.
>  *(Note from OP: The idea behind this clue was that instead of writing words, I'd just perform an action and wave at you. The animation itself was meaningless, which is why I wasn't so happy with this clue.)*

3. Question|noitseuQ

> Two sides to every question (all credit to pac on this one).

4. Confirmed, now with a better explanation.

> The fastest way to a man's heart is through his stomach.
>  Ventriculus gaster is the stomach.  The symbol for male at the top (surrounded by C and R. Clupea Harengus is a herring, and Rouge is red in French. The sign posts for Rouge and Clupea (red herring as pac said) point one way (the wrong way), and the other two point the other direction. You have to go through Ventriculus to get to Cor, where Cor is Latin for heart (thanks to OP for this note).

5. I'm just flat out impressed with this one.

> **Out of sight, out of mind.**
>
>  The clue is out of sight, and if someone is mad, then they could be said to be out of their mind.
>  *(Note from OP: Perhaps because this [usage of mad](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mad) is "chiefly British" is why this one took so long to solve.)*

6. Not sure if this is intentional or not, but

> Hidden in plain sight. Found by editing.

Comment: And it's a good start..

Comment: *Nice* work on 6!

Comment: Yeah I was expecting 6 to take a bit longer.

Comment: You're right with 4. Can you work out the rationale. 5 isn't correct however

Comment: @pacoverflow Know those days when you can't read or think right... yeah, that's my life ;) Thanks for the fix, and sorry for the error.

Comment: No worries.  BTW, #5 isn't hidden madness - someone else guessed that (in a now deleted post) and James said that's not it.

Comment: I like your answer for #2, but still not what I was thinking. 5 isn't correct.

Comment: Your rationale for #4 is correct, including the fact that you have to go through Ventriculus. Well done. Cor is apparently Latin for heart according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart). The clues for red herring in that clue are indeed a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: For #4 you have the wrong meaning of "mad"

Comment: @JamesWebster A new edit is up!

Comment: Still not right I'm afraid. I can't really think of hints.. Quick meta question: If I wanted to give the answers, does it make more sense to edit yours just to complete it, or to post my own answer? Before I give up I'll try and think of some clues.

Comment: @JamesWebster I think that would be a good one to post on the meta site for a community response.

Comment: I've added some hints to the question.

Comment: [And so I did](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/how-should-i-respond-to-partial-answers-to-multi-part-questions)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

2. [GIF of a guy waving]

> The text description of the GIF says "YOU'RE IN MY SOURCE CODE!"  Is it an Easter Egg?  Or perhaps it refers to how many programming language tutorials start off with a basic "Hello World!" program.  The OP did [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15680/what-are-the-common-forms-of-these-sentences/15691#comment48631_15680) that this doesn't work as well as the others.

3. Question|noitseuQ

> There are two sides to every question.

4. [ASCII art signpost]

> Like Aggie Kidd said, this has C-MALE-R and Ventriculus Gaster is the stomach.  It also has "Rouge" which means red and "Clupea Harengus" which is Atlantic herring, so some sort of red herring is involved here.

5. MAD! in a spoiler

> Anger beneath the surface?

Comment: 3 is spot on. 2 is a good answer, but it's not what I was thinking. 4 has got the second part of the clue, but misinterpreted it a bit